# How can i use HTU21D-F sensor with SC16IS750 breakout board?

Tags: sensor, i2c, uart

i have a HTU21D-F humidity and temperature sensor. I want to take data from this sensor on I2C and transformed to UART with SC16IS750 breakout board. And i want to see this signal on an oscilloscope. I've tried this before, and i saw just a straight line on the oscilloscope.By the way i didn't use any microcontroller. I used a power supply. Anybody try this before?

Comment: Can you edit your question with links to the sensor and breakout board?  Also, please show how you have things connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTU21D-F sensor has an I2C interface, and acts as a peripheral device, meaning that it sits idle until it receives an I2C transaction from an I2C master.

The [SC16IS740](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/SC16IS740_750_760.pdf) is also an I2C peripheral, also sitting idly until it receives an I2C transaction from an I2C master. Quoting the datasheet:

> The SC16IS740/750/760 is a slave I2C-bus/SPI interface to a single-channel high
>   performance UART.

There is no way for your system to operate as-is, since there is no microcontroller or other bus master to actually make an I2C request to the sensor, receive the response, and then transmit it to the UART in another I2C transaction. You will need to use a microcontroller to perform this conversion (in this case you can skip the SC16IS740 entirely if the microcontroller has its own UART), or possibly bypass UART entirely and interface the device to a computer directly using a USB bridge capable of acting as an I2C master.